# External checkpoints to S3 on EMR

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, emr, amazon-emr, rocksdb

I am trying to deploy a production cluster for my Flink program.  I am using a standard hadoop-core EMR cluster with Flink 1.3.2 installed, using YARN to run it.

I am trying to configure my RocksDB to write my checkpoints to an S3 bucket. I am trying to go through these docs: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/aws.html#set-s3-filesystem.  The problem seems to be getting the dependencies working correctly.  I receive this error when trying run the program:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.addResource(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.initialize(EmrFileSystem.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopFileSystem.initialize(HadoopFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:350)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:389)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:293)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStreamFactory.<init>(FsCheckpointStreamFactory.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsStateBackend.createStreamFactory(FsStateBackend.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateBackend.createStreamFactory(RocksDBStateBackend.java:273
```

I have tried both leaving and adjusting the core-site.xml and leaving it as is.  I have tried setting the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` to the `/usr/lib/hadoop/share` that contains(what I assume are) most of the JARs described in the above guide.  I tried downloading the hadoop 2.7.2 binaries, and copying over them into the flink/libs directory.  All resulting in the same error.

Has anyone successfully gotten Flink being able to write to S3 on EMR?

EDIT: My cluster setup

AWS Portal:

```
1) EMR -> Create Cluster
2) Advanced Options
3) Release = emr-5.8.0
4) Only select Hadoop 2.7.3
5) Next -> Next -> Next -> Create Cluster ( I do fill out names/keys/etc)
```

Once the cluster is up I ssh into the Master and do the following:

```
1  wget http://apache.claz.org/flink/flink-1.3.2/flink-1.3.2-bin-hadoop27-scala_2.11.tgz
2  tar -xzf flink-1.3.2-bin-hadoop27-scala_2.11.tgz
3  cd flink-1.3.2
4  ./bin/yarn-session.sh -n 2 -tm 5120 -s 4 -d
5  Change conf/flink-conf.yaml 
6  ./bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 1 ~/flink-consumer.jar
```

My conf/flink-conf.yaml I add the following fields:

```
state.backend: rocksdb
state.backend.fs.checkpointdir: s3:/bucket/location
state.checkpoints.dir: s3:/bucket/location
```

My program's checkpointing setup:

```
env.enableCheckpointing(getCheckpointRate,CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)
env.getCheckpointConfig.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION)
env.getCheckpointConfig.setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(getCheckpointMinPause)
env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointTimeout(getCheckpointTimeout)
env.getCheckpointConfig.setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1)
env.setStateBackend(new RocksDBStateBackend("s3://bucket/location", true))
```

If there are any steps you think I am missing, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you installed Flink `1.3.2` on your own on the EMR Yarn cluster, because Amazon does not yet offer Flink `1.3.2`, right?

Given that, it seems as if you have a dependency conflict. The method `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.addResource(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration)` was only introduced with Hadoop `2.4.0`. Therefore I assume that you have deployed a Flink `1.3.2` version which was built with Hadoop `2.3.0`. Please deploy a Flink version which was built with the Hadoop version running on EMR. This will most likely solve all dependency conflicts.

Putting the Hadoop dependencies into the `lib` folder seems to not reliably work because the `flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber.jar` appears to have precedence in the classpath.

Comment: You are correct that I have installed `1.3.2` on the EMR Yarn cluster, however I am using a version of `1.3.2` that uses Hadoop `2.7`(As that is the Hadoop version the EMR instance has installed). `flink-1.3.2-bin-hadoop27-scala_2.11` is the tar file containing the binaries I am using.  Is using binaries the problem perhaps? Should i be installing from source, or should that not matter?

Comment: That should not matter. Hmm then this Hadoop `<= 2.3.0` `Configuration` must come from somewhere else. Could you check the logs and list the complete classpath which is listed there?

Comment: `Classpath: /home/hadoop/flink-1.3.2/lib/flink-python_2.11-1.3.2.jar:/home/hadoop/flink-1.3.2/lib/flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.3.2.jar:/home/hadoop/flink-1.3.2/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/hadoop/flink-1.3.2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar:/home/hadoop/flink-1.3.2/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.3.2.jar::/etc/hadoop/conf:`

Comment: Could you check whether `flink-shaded-h‌​adoop2-uber-1.3.2.ja‌​r` contains the right Hadoop `Configuration` class by extracting the class and decompiling it via `jad`. Then you can check whether it has the method `addResource(Configuration)`. Moreover, please make sure that `flink-1.3.2/lib` does not contain any other dependency which could pull in the wrong Hadoop version.

Comment: I do see the function `public void addResource(Configuration conf)
  {
    addResourceObject(new Resource(conf.getProps()));
  }`.  My flink-1.3.2/lib folder contains the following: `flink-dist_2.11-1.3.2.jar  flink-python_2.11-1.3.2.jar  flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.3.2.jar  log4j-1.2.17.jar  slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar`.  I don't think there would be any conflicts there.

Comment: Hmm, then the conflict must come from one of the dependencies which are brought in by EMR's Yarn cluster. This is strange, though.

Comment: I did a pretty standard install, I can try and make it so hadoop 2.7.3 is the only installed feature in the EMR Cluster however and see if that fixes it

Comment: Same problems, maybe I am missing a step of some sort? I will update OP with steps I do when starting the cluster

Comment: I am facing the same issue, any luck figuring it out?