# Flink write to S3 on EMR

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-flink

I am trying to write some outputs to S3 using EMR with Flink. I am using Scala 2.11.7, Flink 1.3.2, and EMR 5.11. However, I got the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.addResource(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.initialize(EmrFileSystem.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopFileSystem.initialize(HadoopFileSystem.java:345)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:350)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:389)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:293)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileOutputFormat.open(FileOutputFormat.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.TextOutputFormat.open(TextOutputFormat.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.OutputFormatSinkFunction.open(OutputFormatSinkFunction.java:61)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:376)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:702)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-core" % "1.3.2",
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-scala_2.11" % "1.3.2",
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-streaming-scala_2.11" % "1.3.2",
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-shaded-hadoop2" % "1.3.2",
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-clients_2.11" % "1.3.2",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-avro" % "1.3.2",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-filesystem" % "1.3.2"
)
```

I also found this post, but it didn't resolve the issue: [External checkpoints to S3 on EMR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46157946/external-checkpoints-to-s3-on-emr)

I just put the output to S3: `input.writeAsText("s3://test/flink")`. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the good combination for flink-shaded-hadoop and EMR version. After several round of tries and failures, I was able to write to S3 by using a new version of `flink-shaded-hadoop2` -- `"org.apache.flink" % "flink-shaded-hadoop2" % "1.4.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably due the fact that some libraries are loaded by EMR/Yarn/Flink before your own classes, what leads to NoSuchMethodError: classes loaded are not the one you provided, but the one provided by EMR. Take care of the classpath in the JobManager/TaskManager logs.
A solution is to put your own jars in the Flink lib directory to that they are loaded before EMR ones.